# Authoring jQuery Plugin that Requires Other Plugins

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm currently authoring a jQuery plugin which will require another plugin to work (specifically, [Ben Alman's doTimeout](https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-dotimeout/)

**What is the best practice to specify another plugin as a dependency in my project?**

If I were to upload my project to github... is it appropriate to include a copy of [doTimeout](https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-dotimeout/) in my repo? Is this purely a matter of documentation?

I've tried to find this answer via google and stackoverflow, but haven't really found the answer I'm looking for. I'm sure this has already been asked somewhere, so I apologize in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best practice is to simply properly document it.  "This plugin requires XXX plugin to be included before it is."

Be sure to include it in all examples, etc.

If you look around at existing plugins, this is the *de-facto* standard for every plugin that depends on another.

Answer (score 1):

There is no industry standard on registering dependencies between JS libraries, but there is an attempt called AMD (asynchronous module definition). It's used by some major libraries including jQuery. But as you probably guessed, you can register dependencies only if the other party also makes use of AMD.

To get more information you can read these [two](http://addyosmani.com/writing-modular-js/) [articles](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html).

However, I'd agree with Hugo that it's best to document your requirements, accept that JS is a faulty language and have an agreement among developers on how this should be documented rather than having to read another pointless book about ongoing hype.

Comment: Thanks for the articles and information! This will definitely be an option I purse in the future.

Answer (score -1):

You could use http://yepnopejs.com/ for this instead of coding it by yourself. Just 1.7 KB to load CSS or JS and then execute code after loading.

Comment: This doesn't address the organizational and best practices parts of the question.